Boot error / data corruption Redhat 7.9
After rebooting a Redhat 7.9 system, I am faced with data corruption on first partition (dev/sda1)
The System is a VM and last shutdown was graceful from within the OS, no power off, hard stop etc.
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda            8:0    0   150G  0 disk
├─sda1         8:1    0   999M  0 part /boot
└─sda2         8:2    0   149G  0 part
  ├─vg1-root 253:0    0  15.4G  0 lvm  /
  ├─vg1-swap 253:1    0  16.2G  0 lvm
  ├─vg1-home 253:2    0  15.4G  0 lvm  /home
  └─vg1-u01  253:3    0  76.9G  0 lvm  /u01

The system starts in emergency mode, while observing the logs, I found the following entry:
XFS (sda1) Corruption warning: Metadata has LSN (6:627) ahead of current LSN (5:6697) 
XFS (sda1) log mount/recovery failed: error -22
XFS (sda1) log mount failed

I do have just limited knowledge which options I have to recover from this.
xfs_repair is failing, suggesting usin -l option, which might cause further corruption.
Any help highly appeciated.

Running xfs_repair with -L option did the trick.
System is back online.
